# How do you create array literals with HJScript or indeed HJavaScript?

Tags: javascript, haskell, package, dsl

In HJavaScript there is the [`Array` type](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HJavaScript/0.4.7/doc/html/Language-HJavaScript-Syntax.html#g:6), but I can't see a way of constructing a literal that would translate, for example, to JS as `[1,2,3]`. I don't want to have to create a `new Array()` and then push items into it, if I don't have to.

Ideally I'm after a function like `array :: [t] -> Array t`.

I could possibly use `JConst` to implement `array`, but it seems like a hack for something that should be straight-forward. I could also do the create-and-push method above to implement `array`, this is also not great, though.

Here is `array` by pushing; not so great.

```
array :: [Exp a] -> JS (JArray a)
array xs = do
  arr <- new Array ()
  mapM_ (`push` arr) xs
  return arr
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is the first I've heard of HJscript.  Briefly looking at the docs, I can't see any way to make a simple array literal like `[1,2,3]`.  But, I do see a way to call functions, and note that `[1,2,3] = Array(1,2,3)`.  In fact, I'll bet interpreters treat the former as sugar for the latter.  So if you can call functions, you can construct literals.

Comment: Hmm, seems like you might have to use `JConst "Array"` to get at that constructor though.  Seems like less of a hack than using `JConst` for the whole literal though (effectively circumventing quasiquoting).

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no quasiquoting in HJScript. It's an embedded dsl that uses Haskell syntax directly.

Comment: I tried to define an instance for `Args [Exp a] a => HasConstructor (Array a) [Exp a] a`, so I could call the Array constructor with multiple arguments, but I cannot define an instance of `Args a a => Args [a] a` because the showsArgs method is not exported. It really annoys me when methods aren't exported. HaskellDB also has this problem, I can't extend it because methods are hidden. I can define multiple instances of `HasConstructor`:
`instance HasConstructor (Array (JString,JString)) (JString,JString) (String,String)` but this is tedious when I want to construct with a list or other type.

Comment: Access to the function doesn't help because `[1,2,3] = new Array(1,2,3)`, not `[1,2,3] = Array(1,2,3)`. And new has type: `new :: (HasConstructor o e t) => o -> e -> HJScript (Exp o)` Maybe I ought to speak to the author.

Comment: It seems that `Array` is indeed equivalent to `new Array` because it creates a new object anyway (see ECMAScript spec page 121, section 15.4.1).